# in extjs how to bind store to view which is included as item in other view

Tags: view, extjs4, store

i am working in extjs. i have view as-
QbqnsResultmain.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsResultmain',  
        {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsResult'
              ],
              id:'QbqnsResultmainId',
              alias:'widget.QbqnsResultmain',
              title:'Result',
              height:400,
              items:[
                     {
                         xtype:'QbqnsResult',

                     },
                     ],
                     buttons:[
                              {
                                  xtype:'button',
                                  fieldLabel:'review',
                                  action:'getreview',
                                  name:'review',
                                  formBind:true,
                                  text:'Review',

                              },
                              {
                                  xtype:'button',
                                  fieldLabel:'papers',
                                  action:'getpapers',
                                  name:'papers',
                                  formBind:true,
                                  text:'Get all papers',
                             },
                           ]});
```

and QbqnsResult.js-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.QbqnsResult',
{
        extend:'Ext.view.View',
        id:'QbqnsResultId',
        alias:'widget.QbqnsResult',
        //store:'kp.PollStore',
        store:'qb.QbqnsStore',
        config:
        {
            tpl:'<tpl for="1">'+
                '<div id="main">'+
                '</br>'+
                //'<b>Question :-</b></br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Total number of Questions are:-</h1>{TotalQuestions}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Number of attempted Questions:-</h1> {Attempted}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Number of correct answers:-</h1> {CorrectAnswers}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Total score:-</h1> {Total}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">Score you got is:-</h1> {Score}</br>'+
                '<h1 id="q">percentage you got is:-</h1> {percentage}</br>'+

            '<p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
            itemSelector:'div.main',    
        }
});
```

On click of submit button,i want to show above view. So i had written code in controller as-

```
check:function()
    {
    var resultStore=Ext.create('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore');
            proxy=resultStore.getProxy();
            Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            read:'index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/getResult',
            create:'index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/getResult'
            });

            Ext.apply(proxy.reader,{
                type:'json',
                //root:'polls',
                root:'questions'
            });

            Ext.apply(proxy.writer,{
                type:'json',
                //root:'polls',
                root:'data'
            });


        var getdata=this.getLocalvalue();
        console.log(getdata.data);
        Paperno=getdata.data.questionPaperNo;
        UserId=getdata.data.userId;

        var answers = '{"data":[';
        answers = answers + '{"paperNo":"'+Paperno+'","userId":"'+UserId+'"}';
        answers =answers+']}';
        console.log(answers);

        resultStore.load({
            params:{
                data: answers
            },
            callback: function(records,operation,success){
                console.log(records);
                console.log("Successfully data send");
            },
            scope:this
        });

        var temp= Ext.getCmp('qbqnsId');
        temp.removeAll();


        var worldChaptor3 =temp.add({xtype:'QbqnsResultmain',
                id:'QbqnsResultmainId',
                store:resultStore});

},
```

So i want to bind resultStore to QbqnsResult view's tpl which i have included as xtype in QbqnsResultmain view. But resultStore get binded to Qbqnsresultmain view but not to Qbqnsresult which is included as item in it by means of its xtype. So how to bind store to it. Can someone guide me

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it can be:

```
var worldChaptor3 =temp.add({xtype:'QbqnsResultmain',
            id:'QbqnsResultmainId',
            store:resultStore});

worldChaptor3.down('QbqnsResultmain > QbqnsResult').bindStore(resultStore);
```

But, it would be better if you do it in your `QbqnsResultmain`, i'll do it on the `afterrender` event, that way, you can bind the store  automatically on creation.